# Модальное окно с описанием товара

Tags: php, mysql

у меня в  модальное окно выводится описание товара,сейчас у меня выводится только описание первого товара на каждом товаре,подскажите как сделать чтобы модальное окно открывало именно нужное описание товара.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$query = mysqli_query ($db,"select * from goods");
while ($tovar = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
{
  echo " <style>
   div {
    margin-top: 8px;
   }
  </style>
  <div class='col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6'>
<div class='card'>

              <div class='view overlay'>
               <img src='{$tovar['pic']}' class='card-img-top'>
                <a>
                  <div class='mask rgba-white-slight'></div>
                </a>
              </div>

              <div class='card-body text-center'>
                <a href='#' class='grey-text'>
                  <h5>Арт.{$tovar['id']}</h5>
                </a>
                <h5>
                  <strong>
                    <a href='' class='dark-grey-text'>{$tovar['name']}
                    </a>
                  </strong>
                </h5>

                <h4 class='font-weight-bold blue-text'>
                  <strong>{$tovar['price']} Руб.</strong>
                </h4>
                <h3 class='font-weight-normal'>

                <button type='button' class='btn btn-blue-grey' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalCart'><i class='fas fa-shopping-cart'></i></button>


<button type='button' class='btn btn-green' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModalPreview'>
<i class='far fa-caret-square-down'></i></button>
</button>

<div class='modal fade right' id='exampleModalPreview' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalPreviewLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
  <div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <h5 class='modal-title' id='exampleModalPreviewLabel'>Modal title</h5>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>
          <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-body'>

      <div class='col-12'>

   <h6><p class='text-dark'>{$tovar['more']}</p></h6>


   </div>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-footer'>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' data-dismiss='modal'>Закрыть</button>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-elegant'>Добавить в корзину</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


                 </h3>

                </div>
              </div>

</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Смотря как вы выводите описание товара. Нужен пример вашего кода

Comment: Добавил пример кода

Comment: Добавил полный код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сложно ведь поддерживать подобный код. Начните с [изолирования](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) `php` от `html`.Отыщите ресурсы на которых рассматривается пример CRUD-приложения.

---

Получите предварительно все товары перед выводом в `html`:

```
<?php

// Данный код далек от показательного и тем более обучающего.
// Использован только для демонстрация того, что был получен массив товаров с БД.

include 'connect.php';

$query = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM goods');

$products = [];

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $products[] = $row;
}

?>
```

Выводим товары в `html`. Разметка схожа с вашей, но главное обратите внимание на кнопку, по которой будет открываться модальное окно с описанием товара.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <?php if (empty($products)): ?>
      <div class="alert alert-info">Товары отсутствуют.</div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="view overlay">
            <img src="<?= $product['pic'] ?>" class="card-img-top">
          </div>
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <h5 class="grey-text">Арт. <?= $product['id'] ?></h5>
            <h5><a href="#" class="dark-grey-text"><?= $product['name'] ?></a></h5>
            <h4 class="font-weight-bold blue-text"><?= $product['price'] ?> Руб.</h4>
            <button type="button"
              class="btn btn-outline-dark"
              data-toggle="modal"
              data-target="#detailModal"
              data-whatever="<?= $product['id'] ?>"
              >Описание товара</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Модальное окно. Одно на все товары, изначально скрытое. -->

<div id="detailModal" class="modal fade right" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="detailModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Ошибка</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">Выбранный товар не найден.</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Добавить в корзину</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Добавим переменную из `php` в `javascript`. Избавит от нужды парсить DOM.
// Это будет список всех товаров - массив объектов.
const products = <?= json_encode($products, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ?>;

// Данная функция выполняется перед показом модального окна `bootstrap`.
$('#detailModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  // Кнопка, по которой был произведен щелчок.
  const button = $(event.relatedTarget);

  // Идентификатор товара, взятый с атрибута кнопки `data-whatever`.
  const id = button.data('whatever');

  // Найдем товар по `id` из списка всех товаров.
  const product = products.find(function(item, index) {
    return id == item.id
  });

  // Заголовок модального окна.
  $(this).find('.modal-title').text(product.name);

  // Описание выбранного товара.
  $(this).find('.modal-body').text(product.more);
})
</script>
```

Comment: Сделал как Вы сказали,все выводится,но  модальное окно с описанием выводится пустым

Comment: Попробовал,так же ничего не поменялось.

Comment: Google Chrome,ошибки не было

Comment: Ошибок нет,в консоли все выводится, включая 'more'

Comment: Нет,все на месте,код в точности как в вашем ответе.

Comment: Да, он тоже пустой