# Диаграмма javascript+php

Tags: javascript, php

есть такой вот код,как сделать так чтобы значения брались из базы данных?

```
 <script>
      var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: ['Диски', 'Шины', 'Масло', 'Колодки', 'Услуги', 'Фары'],
          datasets: [{
            label: 'Продано',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
              'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
          }]
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      });

    </script>
```

Comment: Их сначала нужно записать в БД, потом выбрать из БД и по такому же [принципу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/991001/256824) передать в `javascript`

Comment: Но ведь там вывод был в код html, а здесь надо вывести в скрипт, т.е необходимо объявить переменные в этом скрипте,и сделать второй скрипт с подключением?

Comment: Ну так и там переменная со всеми товарами в `js` выводилась `const products = <?= json_encode(...) ?>`. Вам с БД нужно разобраться, а там хоть по ajax можно подгружать данные.