# Вывод в Input в модальном окне

Tags: javascript, php

мне надо сделать так чтобы данные из таблицы выводились в инпуты в модальном окне,я попытался сделать [Как вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/990874/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0) , но они выводятся просто в модальном окне при нажатии кнопки

```
   <?php
include 'connect.php';
$query = mysqli_query ($db,"select * from feedback");
$messages = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
  $messages[] = $row;
} 
?>
 <?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>
   <tbody>
          <tr>
          <td class="pt-3-half"><?= $message['id'] ?></td>
            <td class="pt-3-half"><?=$message['name'] ?></td>
            <td class="pt-3-half"><?= $message['email'] ?></td>
            <td class="pt-3-half"><?= $message['tel'] ?></td>
            <td class="pt-3-half"><?=$message['type'] ?></td>
            <td class="pt-3-half"><?= $message['information'] ?></td>
            <td class="text-center">
  <a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-rounded mb-" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalContactForm" data-whatever="<?=$message['id']?>">Ответить</a>

</td>

<?php endforeach; ?>


<div class="modal fade" id="modalContactForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header text-center">
        <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Ответ</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body mx-3">
        <div class="md-form mb-5">

          <input type="text" id="form34" class="form-control validate" value=<?=$messages['name'] ?>
          <label  for="form34" >Имя клиента</label>
        </div>

        <div class="md-form mb-5">
          <input type="email" id="form29" class="form-control validate" value=<?=$messages['email'] ?>
          <label  for="form29">Е-мейл клиента</label>
        </div>

        <div class="md-form">

          <textarea type="text" id="form8" class="md-textarea form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
          <label  for="form8">Ответ пользователю</label>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button class="btn btn-unique">Отправить<i class="fas fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</tr>
</tbody>
    </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Добавим переменную из `php` в `javascript`. Избавит от нужды парсить DOM.
// Это будет список всех товаров - массив объектов.
const messages = <?= json_encode($messages, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ?>;
console.log(messages)

// Данная функция выполняется перед показом модального окна `bootstrap`.
$('#modalContactForm').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  // Кнопка, по которой был произведен щелчок.
  let button = $(event.relatedTarget);

  // Идентификатор товара, взятый с атрибута кнопки `data-whatever`.
  let id = button.data('whatever');

  // Найдем товар по `id` из списка всех товаров.
  let message = messages.find(function(item, index) {
    return id == item.id
  });

  // Заголовок модального окна.
  $(this).find('.modal-title').text(message.name);

  // Описанние выбранного товара.
  $(this).find('.modal-body').text(message.name);
   $(this).find('.modal-body').text(message.email);


})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `но они выводятся просто в модальном окне` ну так вы указывайте им куда вы хотите, чтобы они выводились, а не просто в блок `$(this).find('.modal-body').text(message.email);`

Comment: $(this).find('.value').text(message.email);
$(this).find('.value').text(message.name); Сделал вот так,но выводятся пустые инпуты

Comment: https://jquery-docs.ru/find/

Comment: Все равно что-то не догоняю в чем проблема

Comment: А в чём проблема без js это сделать? Зачем потом парсить dom надо будет?

Comment: @InDevX, покажите ваш вариант без `js` либо вникните в суть проблемы.

Comment: @Jkaer23, откройте [документацию](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/#varying-modal-content), там вариант с `input`-ами.