# Передать id в форму

Tags: javascript, php, html

Есть таблица с кнопками на всплывающую форму, id берет с БД

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-primary" 
        data-toggle="modal" 
        data-target="#feedbackFormModal_'.$result['id'].'">
 Ответ</button>
```

сама форма:

```
  <form id="feedbackForm_id" 
        action="/feedback/process/process.php" 
        enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
    .... код
  </form>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста - как сделать так, что бы id передавался в форму?

Comment: **что бы id передавался в форму** т.е вы хотите отправить `id` с данными формы ?

Comment: @Arsen id уже получен, у каждой кнопки свои id, теперь его нужно передать в саму форму

Comment: ``элементФормы.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<input type="hidden" value="${переменнаяСоЗначениемId}">`);`` если "передать в форму" == "добавить к ее полям".

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/991001/256824

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я нашел ответ с помощью js

кнопка

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#myModal" data-id="'.$result['id'].'" data-category="'.$result['id'].'">кнопка</a>
```

js скрипт

```
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var clickedLink = $(event.relatedTarget); // clickedLink that triggered the modal
        var id = clickedLink.data('id'); // Extract info from data-id attributes
        var category = clickedLink.data('category'); // Extract info from data-category attributes
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('.modal-body').load('remote.php',{var1:id,var2:category});
    });
```

Всплывающая форма

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">форма</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```